# filter in pivot table keys

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to filter using a dynamic key into PivotTable.

I have 3 tables, defined below. When I don't use `group by`, my query uses a `LEFT JOIN` statement and results in something like this:

[image: Example 1]
<sub>(source: [maverabilisim.com](http://maverabilisim.com/temp/issue1.jpg))</sub>

Yellow bars are to-columns and the blue bar is the filter condition.

I need it to return something looking like this:

[image: Example 2]
<sub>(source: [maverabilisim.com](http://maverabilisim.com/temp/issue2.jpg))</sub>

using a condition like this: `.... AND v.key_id=1 (color=1)`

How do I build SQL query to reach this result?

My SQL schema/test data:

```
CREATE TABLE `ads` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ads_title` CHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

);


CREATE TABLE `ads_keys` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `key` CHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `inlist` INT(1) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `ads_values` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ads_id` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `key_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `value` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ads_id` (`ads_id`, `key_id`)
);
INSERT INTO `ads` VALUES (1, 'AAA');
INSERT INTO `ads` VALUES (2, 'BBB');
INSERT INTO `ads` VALUES (3, 'CCC');
INSERT INTO `ads` VALUES (4, 'DDD');
INSERT INTO `ads` VALUES (5, 'EEE');
INSERT INTO `ads` VALUES (6, 'FFF');
INSERT INTO `ads_keys` VALUES (1, 'KM', 1);
INSERT INTO `ads_keys` VALUES (2, 'OIL', 0);
INSERT INTO `ads_keys` VALUES (3, 'YEAR', 1);
INSERT INTO `ads_keys` VALUES (4, 'COLOR', 0);
INSERT INTO `ads_keys` VALUES (5, 'SPEED', 0);

INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (1, 1, 1, 89000);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (2, 1, 2, 200);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (3, 1, 3, 2010);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (4, 1, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (5, 1, 5, 180);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (6, 2, 1, 13000);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (7, 2, 2, 150);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (8, 2, 3, 2008);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (9, 2, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (10, 2, 5, 160);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (11, 3, 1, 79800);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (12, 3, 2, 172);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (13, 3, 3, 2008);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (14, 3, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (15, 3, 5, 178);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (16, 4, 1, 56781);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (17, 4, 2, 127);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (18, 4, 3, 2009);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (19, 4, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (20, 4, 5, 156);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (21, 5, 1, 10200);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (22, 5, 2, 205);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (23, 5, 3, 2000);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (24, 5, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (25, 5, 5, 160);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (26, 6, 1, 45877);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (27, 6, 2, 150);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (28, 6, 3, 2009);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (29, 6, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO `ads_values` VALUES (30, 6, 5, 168);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT a.id, a.ads_title,
       MIN(CASE WHEN v.key_id = 1 THEN v.value END) `km`,
       MIN(CASE WHEN v.key_id = 3 THEN v.value END) `year`
  FROM ads_values v JOIN ads a
    ON v.ads_id = a.id 
 -- WHERE a.id = 2 -- if you need to fetch an ad with a particular id
 GROUP BY a.id, a.ads_title
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN v.key_id = 4 AND v.value = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | ADS_TITLE |    KM | YEAR |
---------------------------------
|  1 |       AAA | 89000 | 2010 |
|  2 |       BBB | 13000 | 2008 |
|  6 |       FFF | 45877 | 2009 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd5c2/11)** demo

Comment: Does not have any value (ads_values) if the ads will be like?

Comment: @maverabilisim Can you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: I push a item ads table. I doesn't ads_keys and ads._values. It's not in result.

Comment: It's a row. Just add a row into ads table INSERT INTO `ads` VALUES (7, 'GGG'); I can not show on sqlfiddle. Get an error from sqlfiddle

Comment: Yeah something wrong with sqlfiddle. At least with mysql 5.5.32 instance. BTW you can always switch to 5.1 or 5.6. Anyway if you just insert that row no wonder it doesn't show up in the results. You don't have associated records in ads_values. According to your requirements this ad should at least one row with `key_id = 4` (color) and `value = 1`. Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/982d1/2) with mysql 5.6. You can show on it.

Comment: Thank you for your tips in mysql.Users does not add ads_values. What kind of code to change accordingly.

Comment: In my opinion `ads` based sql  building  query. SELECT * FROM ads instead of SELECT * FROM ads_values. Is it possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35211/discussion-between-peterm-and-maverabilisim)

Comment: I added to 
`HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN 
(v.key_id = 4 AND v.value = 1) AND 
(v.key_id = 3 AND v.value = 2000) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 ` into third sql query (sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2db24/3) . How I using multiple conditions in your query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ads.id, ads.ads_title, `km`.value AS `KM`, `year`.value AS `YEAR`
FROM ads
JOIN ads_values AS `color` ON (`color`.ads_id, `color`.key_id) = (ads.id, 4)
JOIN ads_values AS `km`    ON (`km`.ads_id, `km`.key_id)       = (ads.id, 1)
JOIN ads_values AS `year`  ON (`year`.ads_id, `year`.key_id)   = (ads.id, 3)
WHERE ads.id = 2 AND `color`.value = 1
```

---

Re your comment, I think you are asking if this query works well when the table has many rows.

Here's the output of EXPLAIN, showing that it uses indexes for each of the joins.  The other thing to look for is `rows` which is the estimate of rows to examine.  The numbers are small in the example below, but that might be because we have only a small number of rows in the table.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ads
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: color
         type: const
possible_keys: ads_id
          key: ads_id
      key_len: 10
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: km
         type: const
possible_keys: ads_id
          key: ads_id
      key_len: 10
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: year
         type: const
possible_keys: ads_id
          key: ads_id
      key_len: 10
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
```

For comparison, I ran EXPLAIN on the query in @peterm's answer.  His query has fewer joins, but his query creates a temporary table.  This is usually bad for performance.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: v
         type: ref
possible_keys: ads_id,covering
          key: covering
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 5
        Extra: Using index
```

EXPLAIN is only an estimate.  You should test both queries with your real data.

Comment: Thank you Bill. it's works but it's not support dynamic keys.

Comment: I think this query made up problem for big table. is it possible?